# R: Propensity Score Matching using MatchIt. How to specify desired matching accuracy for different covariates?

Tags: r, nearest-neighbor

I'm rather new to R and especially to the method of matching by propensity scores. My dataset includes two groups of people that differ in whether they were treated or not- unfortunately they also differ significantly in age and disease duration, therefore my wish to match them.

So far this is my code:

```
set.seed(2208)
mod_match <- matchit(TR ~ age + disease_duration + sex + partner + work + academic,
                     data = Data_nomiss, 
                     method = "nearest",
                     caliper = .025)
summary(mod_match)
```

This code works fine, but I wondered whether there is a possibility to weight the importance of the covariates regarding the accuracy of matching? For me it is crucial that the groups are as close as possible concerning age and disease duration (numeric), whereas the rest of the variables (factors) should also be matched, but for my purposes might differ in means a little more than the first two.

While searching for a solution to my problem I came across the request of this one guy, who had basically the same problem http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/matchit-can-I-weight-the-parameters-td4633907.html

In this case it was proposed to combine nearest neighbor and exact matching, but transferred to my dataset this leads to an unproportional reduction of my sample. In the end what I'd like to have is some sort of customized matching process focussing on age and disease duration while also involving the last three variables but in a weaker way.

Does anyone happen to have an idea how this could be realized? I'd be really glad to receive any kinds of tips on this matter and thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `MatchIt` does not provide this functionality. There were two ways to do this instead of using `MatchIt`, but they are slightly advanced. Note that neither use propensity scores. The point of propensity score matching is to match on a single number, the propensity score, which makes the matching procedure blind to the original covariates for which balance is desired.

The first is to use the package `Matching` and include your own weight matrix to `Weight.matrix` in `Match()`. You could upweight age and disease duration in the weight matrix.

The second is to use the package `designmatch` to do cardinality matching, which allows you to specify balance constraints, and it will use optimization to find the largest sample that meets those constraints. In `bmatch()`, enter your covariates of interest into the `mom` argument, which also allows you to include specific balance constraints for each variable. You can require stricter balance constraints for age and disease duration.

Comment: Dearest Noah, thank you so much for your helpful answer! I thought maybe I was missing some information about the MatchIt package and the propensity score matching that could make it work (as for example change the weights of the covariates in the lm and thereby in the propensity scores) - the research drove me crazy, therefore I'm very happy to know that this is not achievable by using MatchIt. So I'll work my way into your suggested alternatives and maybe post a short update as soon as I'm there? :-) Either way, thanks again for your help- now I know where to start :]